# how to translate these numbers to the names in python lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
sushi = ["Kappa Maki", "Tekka Maki", "Salmon Maki","Negi Toro Maki","California Roll","Philadelphia Roll"]

num = input("ORDER SUSHI IN SUNNY SUSHI! Please enter the number of your dish:")

if num in sushi:
      answer= "{} Thank you for ordering Negi Toro Maki! Enjoy your food! {}"
      print(answer.format(num, sushi[num]))
else:
      print("Wrong number!")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework question however your answer lies with the enumerate function for iterating through lists

Comment: `if num in sushi:` is checking if there's literally an item in the list that's equal to `num`. It's not checking if `num` is a valid index in that list. You need to check that it's smaller than `len(sushi)` in order to validate it as an index. But then it'll be off by one compared to the example list, so you'll have to account for that in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try`/`except` here

```
try:
    num = int(input("ORDER SUSHI IN SUNNY SUSHI! Please enter the number of your dish:"))
    answer= "{} Thank you for ordering Negi Toro Maki! Enjoy your food! {}"
    print(answer.format(num, sushi[num - 1]))
except IndexError:
    print("Wrong number!")
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number!")
```

Note the `[num - 1]` is because Python lists are 0-based, so `[0]` is the first element, though the user would enter `1` based on your table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the number entered is within the number of available options. You are checking whether the number entered is an option itself.

Basically, this is what your program does:

```
if 4 in ["Kappa Maki", "Tekka Maki",...]
```

You need:

```
if 4 in [1, 2, 3,...]
```

You need to make the following changes:

```
if num in range(1, len(sushi) + 1):
    answer= "{} Thank you for ordering {}! Enjoy your food!"
    print(answer.format(num, sushi[num - 1]))
```

Note the change in the print statement as well.